# Make test error (Festival 2.0.95 & Windows XP & Cygwin)

Tags: windows-xp, cygwin, text-to-speech, festival

I am following these instructions: 
http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/downloads/festival/2.0.95/do_test

And after

```
cd ../speech_tools
make test
```

I have this:

```
___________
Test Failed
hash regression status. FAILED
```

Any Idea?

After that,if I try:

```
cd ../festival
make test
```

I get:

```
...
voice script status: CORRECT

test modes (script)
text modes
Duration tree extreme for r 3.64693
grep: and: No such file or directory
grep: Settings/...: No such file or directory
....
.... more errors.
....
sed; read error on /cygdrive/c/Documents: Is a directory
modes script completed
...
...
...
modes script status: INCORRECT

test parse (script)
../examples/scfg_parse_text: linre 2: /cygdrive/c/Documents: is a directory
...
parse script status: FAILED
```

Maybe is something about $CLASSPATH and the windows / and spaces and unix \¿?

What should I do? I have an empty response if i type echo $CLASSPATH.

Thanks.

Comment: I'll try again moving the folder to c:\festival

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is:

- Move the folder to C:\

I think that this is not the best, but it worked.